# Is it possible to animate the transition when a controls' data binding changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, infragistics

We have a UserControl that mainly includes a XamTileManager (the actual control shouldn't matter) which is bound to a list of items. When the binding changes, we want to animate the transition between the old and new data with an arbitrary animation. Is that generally possible in WPF?

The alternative would of course be to have two UserControls and animate the change between them, but we want to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a trigger inside the item with a storyboard. When the data changes the trigger will fire and launch the storyboard animation. I found this example which does it for a data binded textblock:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbMessage" Text="{Binding Path=StatusBarText, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0" To="1.0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:2" From="1.0" To="0.0" BeginTime="0:0:5" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

([source](http://michaelscherf.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/how-to-trigger-an-animation-when-textblocks-text-is-changed-during-a-databinding/))

If that isnt quite what you want you can write your own animation by using the  [Binding.TargetUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.targetupdated.aspx) event.